# react native app crashes after pressing notification [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, react-native, push-notification

i'm facing an issue when i tap the received push notification while the app is in background, where my app gives fatal error "Call must be made on main thread, was thrown while invoking complete on target RNFirebaseNotifications", and i applied the solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/notifee/react-native-notifee/issues/166)
which in summary is adding dispatch_sync to the completion handler of didReceiveNotificationResponse in AppDelegate.m, yet it didn't work.

This is my AppDelegate.m

```
// Required to register for notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// IOS 10+ Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
  [RnAlarmNotification didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      completionHandler();
    });
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler: (void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
  [RnAlarmNotification didReceiveNotification:notification];
  completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }
  
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"CCMM"
                                            initialProperties:nil];
  
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
  
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

I found this block in FNFirebaseNotifications.m

```
// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
#if defined(__IPHONE_11_0)
         withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(10_0) {
#else
         withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(10_0) {
#endif
     NSDictionary *message = [self parseUNNotificationResponse:response];
           
     NSString *handlerKey = message[@"notification"][@"notificationId"];

     [self sendJSEvent:self name:NOTIFICATIONS_NOTIFICATION_OPENED body:message];
     if (handlerKey != nil) {
         completionHandlers[handlerKey] = completionHandler;
     } else {
         completionHandler();
     }
}
```

After i added the dispatch_async in the last if else the issue remained, then after changing async to sync, m getting this error "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1029b4be0)" on the dispatch_sync line.

That’s how i added it

```
if (handlerKey != nil) {
         dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         completionHandlers[handlerKey] = completionHandler;
         });
     } else {
         dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         completionHandler();
         });
     }
```